# What is the most widely used C# obfuscator with string encryption?

Tags: c#, string, encryption

What is the most widely used C# obfuscator that supports string encryption?  Either paid or free, but if it is paid, ones that are in the $200 or so price range.

It's really hard to figure out what's good and what's not with all the marketing hype on every company's website.  Looking for first-hand knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

.NET Reactor is widely-used, is solid and features string encryption. See http://www.eziriz.com/

Comment: I've used .NET Reactor recently and can testify to its merits. You can use a Gui tool or integrate it with your MSBuild script.

Answer (score 1):

I tested a lot of obfuscators, however I focused on painless work with WPF (there is very similar question on SO about obfuscators in general). My choice was [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm). It supports string encryption, however I don't know how solid it is.

Anyway, I would recommend CO, the company is listening, this is important, one of current features (fake obfuscation) is my idea ;-D.

**Edit**: the topic I had in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337134/what-is-the-best-net-obfuscator-on-the-market/3639314#3639314

Answer (score 0):

For the last year, we have tested many C# obfuscators, and found that the best one is Babel and you can check it out at http://babelfor.net/
Babel can encrypt strings, values which cannot be determine. And it add loops
and switches within the method to make it next to impossible to see the program flow. It also provide MSIL encryption which completely hide each method.

We have found out that Obfuscators such as Skater, Net Reactor, Spices, obsidium and Eazfuscator do NOT provide much obfuscation only some renaming. de4dot and ILSpy will dump out every bits of code available.

Net Reactor does one stage further it by overlaying and encapsulating the MSIL code with  c++ native code.  But once the cracker breaks thru' this layer (de4dot cannot break in),all the other codes can be compromised. 
Anyway Net Reactor NO longer response to any emails, it has gone radio silence?

Another good obfuscator is Crypto,as  we found that the obfuscated code
is difficult to comprehend as its variable names are so long. However, it does not have the convoluted switches and gotos of the Babel.  Also, Crypto obfuscated code does not work properly or consistently,  it fail our programs several times during our testing. So we have to abandon Crypto also it takes several days for them to response to our emails.

Comment: Does Babel give the facility to rename Public methods/variables?

Comment: No, renaming Public methods are not allowed by babel. To circumvent this, use private methods